# How do I find the letters of a certain word within a Character array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, compare

I need to compare the characters from two different Character Arrays to find the Hidden word inputted by the user.

The goal is to input 2 Strings and to find a word scrambled within the other. 
Ex. The word "tot" is scrambled in the word "tomato"

With the help of some people of the forums, I have implemented character arrays to store the user Strings, but I do not know a way to check each array for the characters needed. I have tried the code below but it always results in the program not being able to find the word. If anyone could provide a better method or solution I'd highly appreciate it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a word"); 
    String word = input.next();
    char[] charOfWrds = word.toCharArray();

    System.out.println("Please enter a hidden word you would like to search for");
    String search = input.next();
    char[] charOfSrch = search.toCharArray();

    if (isContains(charOfWrds, charOfSrch))   
    { 
        System.out.print("The word " + search + " is found in the word " + word);
    } 
    else 
    {
        System.out.print("The word was not found in " + word); 
    }
}
public static Boolean isContains(char[] charOfWrds, char[] charOfSrch) {
    int count = 0;
    for (char cha : charOfWrds) 
    {
        for (char chaaa : charOfSrch) 
        {
            if (cha == chaaa)
                count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == charOfSrch.length)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The problem statement / example does not explain what you mean by "scrambled".  Is the word "tam" scrambled in "tomato"???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static Boolean isContains(char[] charOfWords, char[] charOfSrch) {
    List<Character> searchFor = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Character> searchMe=new ArrayList<>();
    for(char c:charOfWords)
        searchFor.add(c);
    for(char c:charOfSrch)
        searchMe.add(c);

    for(int x=searchFor.size()-1;x>=0;x--){
        if(searchMe.contains(searchFor.get(x)){
            searchMe.remove(searchFor.get(x));
            searchFor.remove(x);//line A
        }                
    }
    return searchFor.size()==0;
}
```

Quick overview of what this does. I converted both of the character arrays into Lists, so that I could use the List methods. Then, I iterated through every character in the word that you need to find, and if I could find it in the other word, I removed it from both of them, meaning that if all the words were removed from the word needed to be find, the word was found in the other word;otherwise it was not.

I assumed that you could not reuse letters in the second word, but if you can, then just remove line A.

Comment: Thanks for the response I tried implementing your code, but in the if statement, there is an error that says that "the method charAt(int) is undefined for the type List<Character>" How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Sorry I mixed up String and List methods. You should be using searchFor.get(x), not searchFor.charAt(x) . I edited the answer.

Comment: I fixed it and the errors are gone, but I needed to switch the Search Lists because the outputs were reversed at first but it works fine now! Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

take

tomato as charOfWrds

tot as charOfSrch

isContains will count 6 because you don't quit when you find a letter of the first word in the second.

t : two times

o : two times

t : two times

try this :

```
if (cha == chaaa){
    count++;
    break;
}
```

but to make this work you need to remove the letter once found from the second string, because if the word you're looking for is "tttt", then this code will give you true even if it's not, but if you remove t when you found it then it should do the trick.

I don't know if that's clear enough for you.

here is the code :

```
public static Boolean isContains(char[] charOfWrds, char[] charOfSrch) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<charOfWrds.length;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<charOfSrch.length;j++){
            if (charOfWrds[i] == charOfSrch[j]){
                count++;
                charOfSrch[j]=' ';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count == charOfSrch.length)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It's working, i tried it with this :

```
String word = "tomato";
char[] charOfWrds = word.toCharArray();


String search = "tot";
char[] charOfSrch = search.toCharArray();
```

But this is ugly, you should try to use the java Api, unless you really have to do it with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You should try regular expression rather than trying to write an algo. 
Build the expression using user input and then match with the desired word.

Answer (score 0):

My idea was similar to what @kirbyquerby provided except that it has a few optimizations.

Instead of using a linear search, after converting each word (the needle and the haystack) to a list, we sort those lists.  This allows us to use binary search which changes the search complexity from O(n^2) to O(n log n).

Additionally, there is no need to remove characters from the needle list as we can just keep track of how many needle characters have been found.  Once we are done searching, we simply compare the number of found needle characters to the total number of needle characters.  If they are equal, we have found our needle.  Lastly, if a needle character is not found, we can stop searching immediately as we know that the entire needle does not exist within the haystack.

```
package hiddenword;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class HiddenWord {
    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        final String haystack = "Tomato";
        final String needle = "tot";

        if (contains(haystack, needle)) {
            System.out.println(haystack + " contains " + needle);
        } else {
            System.out.println(haystack + " does not contain " + needle);
        }
    }

    private static boolean contains(final String haystack, final String needle) {
        // Convert each word to lowercase and into a List.
        final List<Character> haystackChars = toSortedCharacterList(haystack.toLowerCase());
        final List<Character> needleChars = toSortedCharacterList(needle.toLowerCase());
        int foundNeedleChars = 0;

        for (final Character c : needleChars) {
            // Using sorted lists, our search time is be O(n log n) by using
            // binary search instead of O(n^2) using linear search.
            int index = Collections.binarySearch(haystackChars, c);

            // A needle character has been found, remove it from the haystack
            // and increment the count
            if (index >= 0) {
                haystackChars.remove(index);
                ++foundNeedleChars;
            }
            // A needle character was not found. This means that the haystack
            // doesn't contain every character of the needle and we
            // can quit early
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // If we've found all the needle characters, the needle word exists in
        // the haystack word.
        return foundNeedleChars == needleChars.size();
    }

    private static List<Character> toSortedCharacterList(final String input) {
        final List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();

        // Convert primitive array to List
        for (final char c : input.toCharArray()) {
            list.add(c);
        }

        // Sort that thang
        Collections.sort(list);

        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without having to convert the strings to an array with something like:

```
static boolean containsScrambled(String word, String search){
    //loop through each character of the word whose characters we are searching for
    for(int x = 0; x<search.length(); x++){
        //find the current character to check
        String c = search.substring(x, x+1);

        if(word.indexOf(c) >= 0){
            //if the character is in the word, remove the first instance of it
            //as we cannot use that character again
            word.replaceFirst(c, "");
        }else{
            //if the character is not in the word, fail and return false
            return false;
        }
    }

    //if we made it here, all of the characters existed, return true
    return true;
}
```